# Out of two Django forms and two urls only shown up with one form

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

One Django form is handling Excel file, while another one is handling video file. But the video file form never shown up... Would like to get any help if anyone gets an idea on what's happening around my code

settings.py

```
# Media uploading
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')
MEDIA_URL= "/"
```

it happens to claim that my media not available when I run local host and set url to media, so I have no choice but to root it on the root file

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

import hello.views  

urlpatterns = [
    path("", hello.views.upload_file, name="index"),
    path("upVideo", hello.views.showVideo, name="videoUpload"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField()

class Video(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    videoFile= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")
    videoFile= models.FileField(upload_to='somewhere/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.videoFile)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Video

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Video
        fields= ["name", "videoFile"]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms

from .models import Video
from .forms import UploadFileForm,VideoForm

#**************File Upload View****************#
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            extract = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'].file)
            return render (request, 'dataDisplay.html', {'data':extract})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, "index.html",{"form": form})

#**************Video Upload View****************#
def showVideo(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        lastVideo= Video.objects.last()
        videoFile= lastVideo.videoFile
        vForm= VideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        context= {'videoFile': videoFile,
                'vForm': vForm
                }

        if vForm.is_valid():
            vForm.save()
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)
        else:
            vForm = VideoForm()
        return render(request, "index.html",{"vForm": vForm})
```

index.html

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" id="uploadingForm" target="_blank">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <span id="uploadedFile">{{ form }}</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="uploadButton">
</form>

<div id="uploadSection2">
    <span>Option 3: Site Data</span>
    <h1>Video Uploader</h1>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action={% url 'videoUpload' %}>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ vForm.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" disabled> <!-- forcefully disabled until figured out how-->
    </form>
</div>
```

I've gone through some search but still couldn't figured out what happened... still getting no idea why only the `vForm` never turns up... any help is great appreciated!

Comment: Correct indentation of code for method showVideo() to handle GET request also add double quotes for action url in template

Comment: Hi @MdShahbazAhmad I've done adjusting to handle GET request as well, also realigned the indentation. Plus, having double quotes for template... In case for your following-up, it still doesn't appear with the form button...

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional expression in template when handling two different request in same template. Also handle error in view method.

views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # handling POST request
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            extract = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'].file)
            return render(request, 'dataDisplay.html', {'data': extract})
        else:
            # if form is not valid render form with error
            return render(request, "index.html", {"form": form})
    else:
        # handling GET request to render form
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, "index.html", {"form": form})


#**************Video Upload View****************#
def showVideo(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # handling POST request
        lastVideo = Video.objects.last()
        videoFile = lastVideo.videoFile
        vForm = VideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        context = {
            'videoFile': videoFile,
            'vForm': vForm
        }
        if vForm.is_valid():
            vForm.save()
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)
        else:
            # if form is not valid render form with error
            return render(request, "index.html", {"vForm": vForm})
    else:
        # handling GET request to render form
        vForm = VideoForm()
    return render(request, "index.html", {"vForm": vForm})
```

index.html

```
{% if form %}
    <form action="{% url 'index' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" id="uploadingForm" target="_blank" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <span id="uploadedFile">{{ form }}</span>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="uploadButton">
    </form>
{% endif %}

{% if vForm %}
    <div id="uploadSection2">
        <span>Option 3: Site Data</span>
        <h1>Video Uploader</h1>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'videoUpload' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ vForm.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Make sure `localhost:8000/` calls `upload_file()` method and `localhost:8000/upVideo` calls `showVideo()` method.